# Cutting out a fat stroke

Tags: graphics, canvas, 2d, spline, stroke

I want to draw this:
[image]
Two lines following a along a beizer path with equal distance. The fat lines are what I want, the small dotted one is the guiding path.

The image above is done by first stroking the path with width 30, and then with width 25 in the same color as the background. This works OK sometimes, but not if the background isn't plain colored.

I want something like 'clip' with a shape. And I would prefer to do it using standard graphic libraries. Even better the tools that come in most 2d graphics canvases.

Notes:

- I'm using HTML canvas, but I don't think that's important to the problem.
- I can translate the path up and down, but that won't give me the same distance to the center everywhere.
- Maybe it could be done with a gradient stroke, but I'm not sure how those work.

Comment: The question, though verbosely described, is unclear. Programmatically it is simply two parallel bezier splines offset from a source spline. Widget wise, a "tool" that would take a physically drawn reference spline and create the parallel splines. Cilpping? not sure what you mean there.

Comment: I don't know the beizers in the sides. Only the one in the middle. It's not obvious how I can find the outer ones.

Comment: See my answer below. You only need to know the middle one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a way to do this in HTML5 Canvas.

What you want to do is draw a curve - **on an in-memory, temporary canvas** - and then draw the same curve with less thickness and with the `globalCompositeOperation` set to `destination-out` on that same canvas.

That will get you the shape you want, essentially 2 lines with transparency between them.

*Then* you draw that canvas onto the real canvas that has whatever on it (complex background, etc).

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/at3zR/

Comment: Wow, that's pretty awesome! I had no idea canvas had features like that.

Comment: It even exists in PlayN (through which I manipulate canvas) as well: http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Canvas.Composite.html

Answer (score 1):

The following should better illustrate what I meant. There is a simple algorithm that needs to be added to adjust the offset depending on where the control points are located in relation to each other. If I get more time, and remember, I'll add it.

```
bezier.js
/* 
 * 
 * This code was Shamlessly stolen from:
 * Canvas curves example
 *
 * By Craig Buckler,        http://twitter.com/craigbuckler
 * of OptimalWorks.net      http://optimalworks.net/
 * for SitePoint.com        http://sitepoint.com/
 * 
 * Refer to:
 * http://blogs.sitepoint.com/html5-canvas-draw-quadratic-curves/
 * http://blogs.sitepoint.com/html5-canvas-draw-bezier-curves/
 *
 * This code can be used without restriction. 
 */

(function() {

    var canvas, ctx, code, point, style, drag = null, dPoint;

    // define initial points
    function Init(quadratic) {

        point = {
            p1: { x:100, y:250 },
            p2: { x:400, y:250 }
        };

        if (quadratic) {
            point.cp1 = { x: 250, y: 100 };
        }
        else {
            point.cp1 = { x: 150, y: 100 };
            point.cp2 = { x: 350, y: 100 };
        }

        // default styles
        style = {
            //#333
            curve:  { width: 2, color: "#C11" },
            cpline: { width: 1, color: "#C11" },
            point: { radius: 10, width: 2, color: "#900", fill: "rgba(200,200,200,0.5)", arc1: 0, arc2: 2 * Math.PI }
        }

        // line style defaults
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";

        // event handlers
        canvas.onmousedown = DragStart;
        canvas.onmousemove = Dragging;
        canvas.onmouseup = canvas.onmouseout = DragEnd;

        DrawCanvas();
    }

    function controlLine(offset) {
        // curve
        ctx.lineWidth = style.curve.width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = style.curve.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(point.p1.x+offset, point.p1.y+offset);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(point.cp1.x+offset, point.cp1.y+offset, point.cp2.x+offset, point.cp2.y+offset, point.p2.x+offset, point.p2.y+offset);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function controlPoints(/*hidden*/) {
        // control point tethers
        ctx.lineWidth = style.cpline.width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = style.cpline.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(point.p1.x, point.p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(point.cp1.x, point.cp1.y);
            ctx.moveTo(point.p2.x, point.p2.y);
            ctx.lineTo(point.cp2.x, point.cp2.y);
        ctx.stroke();

        // control points
        for (var p in point) {
            ctx.lineWidth = style.point.width;
            ctx.strokeStyle = style.point.color;
            ctx.fillStyle = style.point.fill;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(point[p].x, point[p].y, style.point.radius, style.point.arc1, style.point.arc2, true);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    } 


    // draw canvas
    function DrawCanvas() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        controlLine(-10);
        controlLine(+10);
        controlPoints();
    }

    // start dragging
    function DragStart(e) {
        e = MousePos(e);
        var dx, dy;
        for (var p in point) {
            dx = point[p].x - e.x;
            dy = point[p].y - e.y;
            if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) < style.point.radius * style.point.radius) {
                drag = p;
                dPoint = e;
                canvas.style.cursor = "move";
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    // dragging
    function Dragging(e) {
        if (drag) {
            e = MousePos(e);
            point[drag].x += e.x - dPoint.x;
            point[drag].y += e.y - dPoint.y;
            dPoint = e;
            DrawCanvas();
        }
    }


    // end dragging
    function DragEnd(e) {
        drag = null;
        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        DrawCanvas();
    }


    // event parser
    function MousePos(event) {
        event = (event ? event : window.event);
        return {
            x: event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y: event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
        }
    }


    // start
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    code = document.getElementById("code");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        Init(canvas.className == "quadratic");
    }

})();
```

bezier.html

```
<!--
   bezier.html

   Copyright 2012 DT <dtyree@inkcogito>

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
   Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
   MA 02110-1301, USA.


-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.21" />
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>B&#233;zier Example</title>
 </head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />

 <body>

    <h1>Canvas B&#233;zier Curve Example</h1>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500" class="bezier"></canvas>
    <pre id="code">code</pre>

    <p>This demonstration shows how parallel b&#233;zier curves can be drawn on a canvas element. Drag the line ends or the control points to change the curve.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bezier.js"></script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

styles.css
     /* CSS */
     body
     {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 85%;
        margin: 10px 15px;
        color: #333;
        background-color: #ddd;
     }

```
 h1
 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 0.3em 0;
 }

 h2
 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
 }

 p
 {
    margin: 1em 0;
 }

 #canvas
 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/parallelm.png/ The two lines are not in equal distance from the center, but may get very close and even cross.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it's not a drop in solution; It is only the beginning of the solution. A scaling function needs to be added to adjust the offsets of the control points in relation to each other. If I can get the time, I'll work it out. Basically, it's a 2.5d solution for a 2d plane.

Comment: See this for an explanation... http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/#offsets additionally the d3.js lib has an good function for an offset scale.

Comment: It's not a hard problem but the offset scaling is labor intensive to code, about 10hrs from scratch. I've done it a couple of times in different languages. Graphics programming should make you appreciate math.

Comment: @Dtyree: Where in d3.js's source is their offset scaling code? (I need to implement it for canvas beziers since I'm trying to allow for variable thickness) Thanks